# Lead function with duplicate dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am looking at a legacy payment system and some of the payments have been input with the exact same datetime (to the second) (see the attached image)

What I am trying to achieve is in these instances, add a second to one of them (doesn't matter which) just so I can differentiate the date. I have tried this with a lead function however as both dates are the exact same, it is just going straight to the date after and ignoring the duplicated date.

My lead function looks like this

```
CASE WHEN p.DateCreated = LEAD(DateCreated, 1,0) OVER (partition by TransactionID ORDER BY DateCreated) THEN DATEADD(SECOND,1,DateCreated) ELSE P.DateCreated end [DateCreated]
```

[image]

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this? Thinking it might just be something simple I am overlooking.

Comment: Presumably you also have a primary key in the table? Add that to your `ORDER BY` clause as well for consistent ordering. Ordering by `DateCreated` will generate arbitrary ordering when the rows all have the same value.

Comment: Can the query just be run of a grouping SQL statement, rather than the table as same transaction ID?  Is this all the data in the table?

Comment: No primary key annoyingly.. it's been really poorly built

Answer (score 0):

Try This with CTE and PARTITION BY

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Lead_Date ORDER BY Lead_Date ) AS rno,
      Lead_Date 
  FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte SET Lead_Date =  DATEADD(ss,1,Lead_Date)
WHERE rno=2
```

This query should add 1 second to Lead_Date in duplicate recordings.

Comment: [; Transact-SQL statement terminator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).  why do you start with a semi-colon?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `LAG`.
NB: If there are 3 identical values you will need to run it twice, and so on.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE P (id int, dateCreated datetime);
> ```

> ```
> insert into p values
> (1,'2022-03-03 10:30:00'),
> (2,'2022-03-03 10:30:00'),
> (3,'2022-03-03 10:30:10');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM p;
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE p set dateCreated =  DATEADD(SECOND,1,DateCreated)
> FROM 
> P JOIN 
>  ( SELECT ID, 
>  dateCreated d1 ,  
>  LAG (dateCreated) over(order by dateCreated) d2 from p) P2
> ON p.ID = p2.id
> WHERE dateCreated=d2;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM p;
> ```

> ```
> id | dateCreated            
> -: | :----------------------
>  1 | 2022-03-03 10:30:00.000
>  2 | 2022-03-03 10:30:00.000
>  3 | 2022-03-03 10:30:10.000
>
> id | dateCreated            
> -: | :----------------------
>  1 | 2022-03-03 10:30:00.000
>  2 | 2022-03-03 10:30:01.000
>  3 | 2022-03-03 10:30:10.000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60da3fdf793eeaa73f4750f3c78bcc63)*

Answer (score 0):

As far I have understood your question there is only one thing that is missing in your case when statement which is "an and operator along with a LeadDate condition". Please try the below sample and compare that with your case when.

Edit: Query updated to handle multiple duplicate records of DateCreated and LeadDate

```
declare @tbl table(TransactionId int, DateCreated datetime, LeadDate datetime)

insert into @tbl
values(277090, '2020-04-13 18:50:17.580','2020-04-13 18:50:16.580')
,(277090, '2020-04-13 18:50:17.580','2020-04-13 18:50:16.580')
,(277090, '2020-04-13 18:50:17.580','2020-04-13 18:50:16.580')
,(277090, '2020-04-13 18:50:16.580','1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')

select * from @tbl

;with cte as(
select TransactionId,DateCreated,LeadDate
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by TransactionId order by LeadDate)rownum
from @tbl
)
select TransactionId,DateCreated
, case when lead(DateCreated,1,0)over(partition by TransactionId order by DateCreated) = DateCreated
and lead(LeadDate,1,0)over(partition by TransactionId order by LeadDate) = LeadDate
then DATEADD(SECOND,rownum,LeadDate) else LeadDate end as LeadDate
from cte
```